# Adapter for GridView is not working correctly

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

I'm learning to use gridview in android and I don't know how to solve one problem...
I'm trying to create a manager app using gridview, but I don't know where is the problem in the code.

**StickerGridViewAdapter :**

```
public class StickerGridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Sticker> {

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
List<Sticker> data = new ArrayList<Sticker>();
RecordHolder viewHolder = new RecordHolder();

public StickerGridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Sticker> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Sticker sticker = data.get(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new RecordHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        viewHolder.count = sticker.getAmount();
        viewHolder.textViewNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNumber);
        viewHolder.textViewQuantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewQuantity);
        viewHolder.iv_logo_card = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_logo_card);
        viewHolder.buttonAdd = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
        viewHolder.buttonRemove = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonRemove);
        viewHolder.textViewQuantity.setText(sticker.getAmount().toString());
        paintQuantity(viewHolder.count, viewHolder, context);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (RecordHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (viewHolder.count != 99) {
                viewHolder.count++;
            }
            sticker.setAmount(viewHolder.count);
            StickerBusinessService.saveSticker(sticker);
            viewHolder.textViewQuantity.setText(sticker.getAmount().toString());
            paintQuantity(viewHolder.count, viewHolder, context);
        }
    });

    viewHolder.buttonRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (viewHolder.count != 0) {
                viewHolder.count--;
            }
            sticker.setAmount(viewHolder.count);
            StickerBusinessService.saveSticker(sticker);
            viewHolder.textViewQuantity.setText(sticker.getAmount().toString());
            paintQuantity(viewHolder.count, viewHolder, context);
        }
    });


    viewHolder.textViewNumber.setText(sticker.getNumber().toString());
    return convertView;

}

private static class RecordHolder {
    TextView textViewNumber;
    TextView textViewQuantity;
    ImageView iv_logo_card;
    ImageButton buttonAdd;
    ImageButton buttonRemove;
    int count;
}

public static void paintQuantity(int count, RecordHolder holder, Context context){
    if(count == 0){
        holder.textViewQuantity.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }else if(count == 1){
        holder.textViewQuantity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.textViewQuantity.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.material_green_500));
    }else if(count > 1){
        holder.textViewQuantity.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.material_amber_600));
    }
}

}
```

The `itens`(of the `gridview`) have two button (`ADD` "`+`" and `SUBTRACT` "`-`"), but when I click on the buttons the item(`id=1`) receive the `count = 1`, but if I scroll down others `itens` receive the same count... what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: why are you creating instance of RecordHolder for two times..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not create instance of RecordHolder outside of getView. Already you have created in getView().

Create instance of RecordHolder in getView() like.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   final Sticker sticker = data.get(position);
   RecordHolder viewHolder;
   if (convertView == null) {
      viewHolder = new RecordHolder();
      //remaining code is here
   }else {
     //else part
   }
  return converview;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I correct that, but there's one problem.
Each item has two buttons ( " + " and " - " ), and with this resolution where this part will be ? (viewHolder.buttonRemove and viewHolder.buttonAdd) ?

Answer (score 0):

I made what [Saritha G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4787944/saritha-g) said and its works!
Now my code is this way:

```
public class StickerGridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Sticker> {

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
List<Sticker> data = new ArrayList<Sticker>();

public StickerGridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Sticker> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    final RecordHolder holder;
    final Sticker sticker = data.get(position);
    if (row == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new RecordHolder();
        holder.count = sticker.getAmount();
        holder.textViewNumber = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewNumber);
        holder.textViewQuantity = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewQuantity);
        holder.iv_logo_card = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.iv_logo_card);
        holder.buttonAdd = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
        holder.buttonRemove = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.buttonRemove);
        holder.textViewQuantity.setText(sticker.getAmount().toString());
        paintQuantity(holder.count, holder, context);
        row.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (RecordHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    holder.buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (holder.count != 99) {
                holder.count++;
            }
            //holder.textViewQuantity.setText("" + holder.count);
            sticker.setAmount(holder.count);
            StickerBusinessService.saveSticker(sticker);
            holder.textViewQuantity.setText(sticker.getAmount().toString());
            paintQuantity(holder.count, holder, context);
        }
    });

    holder.buttonRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (holder.count != 0) {
                holder.count--;
            }
            //holder.textViewQuantity.setText("" + holder.count);
            sticker.setAmount(holder.count);
            StickerBusinessService.saveSticker(sticker);
            holder.textViewQuantity.setText(sticker.getAmount().toString());
            paintQuantity(holder.count, holder, context);
        }
    });


    holder.textViewNumber.setText(sticker.getNumber().toString());
    //
    return row;

}

private static class RecordHolder {
    TextView textViewNumber;
    TextView textViewQuantity;
    ImageView iv_logo_card;
    ImageButton buttonAdd;
    ImageButton buttonRemove;
    int count;
}

public static void paintQuantity(int contador, RecordHolder holder, Context context){
    if(contador == 0){
        holder.textViewQuantity.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }else if(contador == 1){
        holder.textViewQuantity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.textViewQuantity.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.material_green_500));
    }else if(contador > 1){
        holder.textViewQuantity.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.material_amber_600));
    }
}
}
```

But the value of each item is repeating when I scroll down the grid... What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Here value means..?? position or sticker value??

Comment: The values is the quatity/amount of item X the user have

Comment: from wer are you getting the amount ..??